# TrafficStats reporting -1 for all applications except my own?

Tags: android, android-networking

I run the following code on my device:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = packageManager
        .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : applications) {
    Log.OUT.debug("NET_THRESHOLD: package = " + applicationInfo.packageName + ", uid = " + applicationInfo.uid + ", rx bytes: " + TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(applicationInfo.uid));
}
```

And it seems to report `-1` (or `TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED`) for every package on my device except for the one I'm calling it from.

Is this intended behavior?

I'm running Android 10 if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this in the android documentation for [`TrafficStats#getUidRxBytes(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int)).

> Starting in `Build.VERSION_CODES.N` this will only report traffic statistics for the calling UID. It will return `UNSUPPORTED` for all other UIDs for privacy reasons. To access historical network statistics belonging to other UIDs, use `NetworkStatsManager`.